# ASP Ajax Calendar Extender and select dare-time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, date, calendar

I am using the Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar Extender control. I want to display the time along with the date. I have tried just setting the Format to "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" but the time section gets default time 12:00:00. If the user wants to change the time section they can do it manually, the calendar drop down is only used for changing the date part.

Are there any workarounds or alternatives to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using  jquery ui datepicker .

html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtdatepicker"/>
```

JQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtdatepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var rda = new Date(); // for now
            datetextwithTime=datetext+" "+rda.getHours()+": "+ rda.getMinutes()+": "+rda .getSeconds();
            $('#datepicker').val(datetextwithTime);
        },
    });
});
```

Fiddle Sample:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/j8Vd8/)